# how do I Import a file from the parent directory in python

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I currently have the following folder structure

```
mypy
    > test_fldr
        > test.py
    
    > user_funcs.py
```

my goal is to be able to access and utilize the functions within the user_funcs.py file by writing an import statement in the test.py file.

I have attempted using relative imports such as the following

```
from .. import user_funcs
```

but this has only came up with errors like this

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

i have also tried importing the library by referencing the parent like so

```
from mypy import user_funcs
```

but that only gave me the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'user_funcs' from 'mypy' (C:\Users\joest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mypy\__init__.cp311-win_amd64.pyd)
```

is there any clean solution that doesn't require using things like sys.path or anything that looks similar to the following as my code editor auto formats the code so all import are at the top which makes thinsg not work and can be very annoying after not long

```
import sys
# example: sys.path(...)
import user_funcs
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python all import paths are relative to the directory where the interpreter is run, so for your `test.py` to be able to access `user_funcs.py` in the parent directory you should have `test.py` import `user_funcs` normally:

```
import user_funcs
```

and run `test.py` from where `user_funcs.py` is (that is, from the `mypy` directory):

```
mypy> python test_fldr/test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `import user_funcs.py`.
if `user_funcs` was in a directory called `funcs`
then you would do `from funcs import user_funcs.py`